# Can't extract table from yahoo finance

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, finance, yahoo

I try to run the below code but still can't get the proper output in Excel with headers. Please help.

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

```
lists = ["FBRX", "GNLN", "TISI"]

result=[] 

for list in lists:
  url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{list}/profile?p={list}"
  wd.get(url.format(list=list))
  add = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Col1-0-Profile-Proxy"]/section/section[1]/table/tbody').text

  print(list,add)
  result.append([list,add])
```

The intended format will be in the below pic.
[image: pic]

Comment: And what do you get?  Those headers are not part of their page, so if you want that header, you'll need to put it in your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an Excel spreadsheet isn't mandatory, then your "result" variable can be saved as a txt file in the same formatting in terms of rows and columns by including the following lines of code afterwards:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# Mout Drive;
from google.colab import drive
myGoogleDrive = drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount = True)
%cd "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks"
fileName = 'InsertNameForFile' + '.txt'
np.savetxt(fileName, result, delimiter = ", ", fmt = '%s')
```

To read that saved txt file at a later point in time:

```
savedResultsFile = pd.read_csv(fileName, header = None).copy()
```